# What do the two different reload times mean in show version output?

Tags: cisco-ios, cisco-commands

We're rebooting several ASR920s from the command line (to upgrade the IOS) and a couple have failed to come back up at first. These two have very different times for `returned to ROM` and `restarted`. What do the two different times indicate? What can I gather about the issue with reloading?

Most of the reloaded routers look like this, with ~20 minutes' difference between `System returned to ROM by reload at` and `System restarted at`:

```
router-i uptime is 1 day, 15 hours, 58 minutes
Uptime for this control processor is 1 day, 16 hours, 0 minutes
System returned to ROM by reload at 22:07:27 PDT Mon Aug 21 2017
System restarted at 22:25:42 PDT Mon Aug 21 2017
System image file is "bootflash:asr920-universalk9_npe.03.16.05.S.155-3.S5-ext.bin"
Last reload reason: PowerOn
```

But the two that didn't immediately come back have large gaps between the times. Over 6 hours:

```
router-a uptime is 1 day, 8 hours, 2 minutes
Uptime for this control processor is 1 day, 8 hours, 4 minutes
System returned to ROM by reload at 23:51:28 PDT Mon Aug 21 2017
System restarted at 06:34:37 PDT Tue Aug 22 2017
System image file is "bootflash:asr920-universalk9_npe.03.16.05.S.155-3.S5-ext.bin"
Last reload reason: PowerOn
```

And over 7 hours:

```
router-c uptime is 7 hours, 24 minutes
Uptime for this control processor is 7 hours, 26 minutes
System returned to ROM by reload at 00:04:41 PDT Wed Aug 23 2017
System restarted at 07:12:28 PDT Wed Aug 23 2017
System image file is "bootflash:asr920-universalk9_npe.03.16.05.S.155-3.S5-ext.bin"
Last reload reason: PowerOn
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Reload indicates that the system was manually reloaded by CLI the 00:00:00 is the time in 24 hr format

System restarted is when the system finally was able to boot to IOS

This is what I am able to infer, Hope this helps

If there is issues between reload and restoration ensure the file path for the boot file is good, then verify the config registrar to ensure default setting.

Comment: That's what I thought. So why would that take 6 or 7 hours?

Comment: Sorry actually just edited my response to include if it is taking abnormally long it might have issues locating the file path for the bootflash:

Answer (score 2):

It appears you restarted the switches with the reload command first (proper restart). That's the rom with reload. The reset time appears to be the time somebody restarted it diffrently like pulling the plug. If you had issues with the update I'm guessing hours later somebody pulled the plug and possible did some work on them to get them to boot.

Comment: That may be the case. I'm trying to figure out the exact sequence of events from the local contacts.
Does a power cycle not reset the `returned to ROM` time?

Comment: Returned to ROM by reload. By reload is the key phrase. Reload is the command to initiate a reboot from cli.

Comment: Right. So I'd expect it to say `returned to ROM by power on` if the power was pulled.